# Conversion of function parameter from signed int to unsigned int

Tags: c, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

In the following code snippet that I stumbled upon the other day which passes a `signed int` to a function that expects an `unsigned int`

```
#include "stdio.h"

void set_data(unsigned int* addr, const unsigned int data)
{
    printf("Inside set_data:%d\n", data);
    *addr = data;
}

int main() {
    unsigned int a = 2;
    printf("Before set_data:%d\n", a);
    set_data(&a, -10);
    printf("After  set_data:%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:-
Note there is no warnings thrown by the compiler:-

```
zhossain@zhossain-linux1:~$ gcc -Wall test.c
zhossain@zhossain-linux1:~$ ./a.out
Before set_data:2
Inside set_data:-10
After  set_data:-10
```

Questions:-
1. Why is the compiler not shouting? implicit conversion?
2. How come "Inside set_data" prints a negative integer while `data` is clearly defined as `unsigned int`
3. Is this by any chance undefined behavior OR implementation defined which may not be a good practice to write safe portable code?

Looking forward to detailed explanation also would appreciate if you can point to relevant SO threads

Comment: Well because an `int` will always fit in `unsigned`, (2) you are telling `printf` to interpret the bits in `a` as an `int` (take a look at `twos-complement` storage of ints for further detail). The code is well-defined.

Comment: #2 `printf("Inside set_data:%d\n", data);` is UB when `data` > `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux - `printf()` has undefined behaviour whenever a format specifier specifies a different type than the corresponding argument.

Comment: @peter C11 §6.5.2.2 6 and §7.21.6.1 9 have a level of inconsistency that may be interpreted as `int/unsigned` values represented the same way with `printf()` lack indistinguishable with `"%u/%d"`.  In this case, OP's `unsigned` value is certainly > `INT_MAX` and so UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)   The compiler is not "shouting" (a more correct description is "issuing a diagnostic") about implicit conversions because the conversion from a `signed` type to `unsigned` type is well defined by the standard - it uses what is (mathematically) known as modulo arithmetic.   The call of `set_data(&a, -10)` does such a conversion of `-10` BEFORE calling `set_data()`.    A value of `-10` when converted to `unsigned` will result in a value of `UINT_MAX - 9` where `UINT_MAX` is obtained from `<limits.h>` and represents the largest value a `unsigned int` can represent.    Compilers can often be configured to give warnings about such conversions but, by default, most compilers are configured NOT to.   If you want warnings, you'll need to read documentation for your compiler to work out how.

2)   All of your calls of `printf()` result in undefined behaviour, since `%d` informs `printf()` that the corresponding argument is of type `int`, and you have passed an `unsigned`  (i.e. a type mismatch).   With your particular implementation, it appears that conversion of values of type `int` to or from `unsigned` does not change the bitwise representation, and the `unsigned` value passed to `printf()` has the same bitwise representation as an `int` with value `-10`.    That is NOT guaranteed by the standard.

3)   As I've said in the previous point, your call of `printf()` has undefined behaviour, due to a type mismatch.   Change the format specifier to `%u` to get well-defined behaviour (and you will then see the value printed will be equal to `UINT_MAX-9`.    The conversion of an `int` with a negative value to `unsigned` - which occurs when calling `set_data()` in `main()` has implementation-defined behaviour since the value of `UINT_MAX` is implementation-defined.   In other words, the value that results from converting `-10` from `int` to `unsigned` is implementation-defined.

Note, also, that the `const` specifier on the second parameter of `set_data()` is redundant, as far as the caller is concerned, since that argument is passed by value.   Even without the `const`, any changes the function makes to `data` will only be visible within the body of `set_data()` and invisible to the caller.

I'm not going to give links to other SO threads, since my answer is reasonably complete without them.   You can search for such links for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - regarding the `const` specifier for the data, I prefer conveying a message to ppl reading/working on this function later - this parameter is not to be messed with - should be written as is..

Comment: Passing by value already conveys that message - as far as the caller is concerned, the value won't change.  Passing by function arguments by value is a foundational concept in C.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your code, I think I understand where your confusion is. You are passing `-10` as `unsigned` value and you are scratching your head with "*Why the hell is it printing `-10` if it is an `unsigned value?*"

It all boils down to bits. The bits for `10` are (using `16` bits to prevent a lot of zeros)

```
0000000000001010
```

In most computers negative values are stored in *twos-complement* format (which is layman terms is an inversion of all bits plus one). If applied twice you get the same number back. So, the *twos-complement* storage for `-10` is:

```
1111111111110110
```

Which will happily fit in and `unsigned` value of the same type.

The next quandary is "*How does it print `-10`?*" As long as your value does not exceed the maximum value for `int`, `"%d"` will happily print the bits you provide as an integer. There is no problem in your code assigning `-10` as `int` and then passing as `unsigned`, because you are passing the value `1111111111110110`. You can print the value as `signed int` (`-10`) or `unsigned int` (`4294967286`).

That's really the only question you are answering for `printf`. What should it do with the bits?, "Do I print `11111111111111111111111111110110` as `unsigned` or do I print it as `int`. That's what you are telling `printf` with `%u` or `%d`.

There is no problem with *Undefined Behavior* as long as you do not attempt to use a value in `a` greater than `INT_MAX` as an `int`. Otherwise, you are fine.

Digest this, and let me know if I understood your concern, or if I missed the mark and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: Yup that was my basic concern. Thanks for the in depth analysis !!